# How to make an IF Statement in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

How can I create a condition in SSIS like below?
I know how to create it just in SQL Server

Example:

```
IIF(LEFT(MAT,1) = '"', NULL,  REPLACE(MAT,'""',''))
```

Comment: You can use an derived column task. There you can write something like `LEFT(MAT,1) == '"' ? NULL : REPLACE(MAT,'""','')`

Answer (score 5):

«boolean_expression» ? «when_true» : «when_false»

LEN([Mobile]) == 9 ? ("0" +  [Mobile]) :  [Mobile]

Answer (score 1):

SET MAT = LEFT(MAT,1) == '"' ? NULL : REPLACE(MAT,'""','');

IFF statement works condition-based assignment

The `IIF()` statement has the following `format`:

```
=IIF( Expression to evaluate,
         what-to-do when the expression is true,
         what-to-do when the expression is false )
```

- **`Parameter1`**: It should be a `Boolean` `Expression`.
- **`Paremeter2`**: This    value will return when `Expression` is `true`.
- **`Paremeter3`**: This value    will return when `Expression` is `false`.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax in SSIS is like this: `[condition] : [value if true] ? [value if false]` With that said, you could do...

`(MAT,1)='' : NULL ? REPLACE(MAT,'""',''))`

Comment: its dobble equal sign in derived colum - This is how you write it . Just like i started in comment: Example is `AnimalName == "Elephant"? "savannah": "unknown"`